# Order Using Multiple Rows acting as one

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have an SQL query

```
$choice = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['choice']);
    
    if($option == "Name")
    $searchresult = "SELECT  id, stationname1, stationinfo1, stationprice1, image1, stationname2, stationinfo2, 
    stationprice2, image2, stationname3, stationinfo3, stationprice3, image3, stationname4, stationinfo4, stationprice4, 
    image4 FROM fuel WHERE stationlocation1 LIKE '%" . $location .  "%' ORDER BY stationname1 $choice"; //search database
```

which gets the data and arranges it by station name 1. The problem is that I have stationnames 1 - 4 which i would like to order together so that all names are in alphabetical order no matter the column. I know that using

```
ORDER BY stationname1 ASC, stationname2 ASC, stationname3 ASC, stationname4 ASC
```

won't work as it orders them individually. Please what do I do to order them together?

Basically something in the form of

```
ORDER BY stationname1 and stationname2 and stationname3 and stationname4 ASC
```

for example...looking at this database [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rcUi.jpg) , i would like it to show:

- another_one
- nnnn
- ordinarytest
- zgkgkgkkg

in that order

Comment: The question would make more sense if "stationname[1|2|3|4]" were values of `stationname`; you'll need to provide more information about your data. Right now I am **guessing** [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) is what you're looking for though. _It's also not clear what you mean by "multiple rows acting as one", did you mean fields?_

Comment: Looks like you need a `CASE` in your order by, but without a sample data and desire output is very hard to provide a more detailed solution.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. I have improved the question if that helps.

Comment: You need to normalize the input first and create a row for each different station name and order by that. So you no longer have 4 different columns for station, just one column.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As others have said, you really should normalize your data so you don't effectively have 4 rows' data per actual row; but this should get you what you want (*and may be a path to normalizing your data*):

```
SELECT  id, stationname1 AS stationname, stationinfo1, stationprice1, image1
FROM fuel 
WHERE stationlocation1 LIKE '%" . $location .  "%' 
UNION
SELECT  id, stationname2 AS stationname, stationinfo2, stationprice2, image2
FROM fuel 
WHERE stationlocation2 LIKE '%" . $location .  "%' 
UNION
SELECT  id, stationname3 AS stationname, stationinfo3, stationprice3, image3
FROM fuel 
WHERE stationlocation3 LIKE '%" . $location .  "%' 
UNION
SELECT  id, stationname4 AS stationname, stationinfo4, stationprice4, image4
FROM fuel 
WHERE stationlocation4 LIKE '%" . $location .  "%' 
ORDER BY stationname $choice;
```

The final `ORDER BY` clause of a `UNION` applies to the entire `UNION` unless parenthesis force it to be otherwise.